# How to start and stop tomcat using java code?

Tags: java, tomcat

How to start and stop tomcat using java code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can execute native commands using java

```
String command = "c:\program files\tomcat\bin\startup.bat";//for linux use .sh
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Comment: i have the same problem and the above solution is not working for me. I followed this solution, though it stops the exception but still tomcat is not starting: http://www.servlets.com/archive/servlet/ReadMsg?msgId=150354&listName=tomcat-user

Comment: @dhaval so what is the exception and what do you exactly mean by not starting

Comment: "The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly" this is the exception. and after using the "command.com /c <startup path>" it stops the exception but tomcat is not starting.

Comment: have you declared `CATALINA_HOME` ?

Comment: @jigar when I start it from the command prompt it runs well. previously I was starting it from another .bat file then also it was running perfect. But with some new changes I now need to call startup.bat directly from Java code which is not running

Comment: `File file = new File("path to tomcat bin");`

`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/C", "start" ,"path to startup.bat", "start"}, null, file);`

This code worked finally

Comment: `File file = new File("path to tomcat bin");
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/C", "start" ,"path to startup.bat"}, null, file);`

- slight change "start" is required if catalina.bat is called

Comment: @dhaval . ok. will try that out if i get a chance

Comment: @jigar sure. maybe your solution didn't work due to change in  environment. Although this should not be the issue but i am running multiple tomcat servers on a single machine.

Comment: You should go for Bootstrap class of tomcat

Answer (score 17):

You can send the shutdown command to the shutdown port both of which are can be configured in the root element of server.xml file of Tomcat.

By steps:

**Step 1**

Configure the CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml  as follow:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="myShutDownCommand">
```

The attribute port is optional. If it is omitted, the default one, 8005, is used.

The value for shutdown attribute can be anything. This should not be known by others.

**Step 2**

Make the java program send the shutdown command, myShutDownCommand, using java.net.Socket class to the shutdown port, 8005.

```
try { 
    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8005); 
    if (socket.isConnected()) { 
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true); 
        pw.println("myShutDownCommand");//send shut down command 
        pw.close(); 
        socket.close(); 
    } 
} catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: this will only shutdown server. In the same way, is it possible to restart the server?

Comment: I was running the server on Eclipse and it didn't stop tomcat.

Comment: Is it possible to execute that code within a running WAR? I get a "javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost" with that code

Answer (score 14):

You need to execute `main` method of `org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap` with the parameter `"start"`.

You also need following things:

- to have `tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar` in your classpath;
- `-Dcatalina.base` to point to `$TOMCAT_HOME`
- `-Dcatalina.home` to point to `$TOMCAT_HOME`
- `-Djava.io.tmpdir` to point to a temporary directory (usually `$TOMCAT_HOME/temp`)

I also have `-noverify` parameter set, not sure if it is always necessary.

p.s. it would also be nice if you could start accepting answers, your current rate is 0/28.

Comment: `-noverify` disables checks during classloading. It makes Tomcat start faster when you have huge web apps at the cost of security.

Comment: Can you be more specific to exceute main method of org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap with the parameter "start". How can we do that. I am facing issue in starting tomcat using bootstrap.jar

Comment: @TanviGarg `Bootstrap` class has `main(String[] args)` method, and the `start` argument must be passed to this `String` array. Normally this is done by shell script which you have to imitate.

Comment: Can i start tomcat using java -jar bootstrap.jar start .

Answer (score 0):

For Linux Users using java, try this:

```
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = run.exec("sh startup.sh", null, new File("filePath"));
filePathexample = /home/example/apache-tomcat-8.0.47/bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

Start (and stop) an embedded Tomcat. It is well documented how to do this, for example [here](http://zetcode.com/web/embeddedtomcat/).