# How to start Tomcat Server programmatically in Java

Tags: java, tomcat

I want to start tomcat server programmatically in JAVA. Please help me

Comment: Look for invoking a new JVM from Java or for starting catalina in a new thread, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Use java Runtime to execute the batch file. Probably run.bat.

Comment: http://blog.faultylabs.com/2011.php?t=ant

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start and stop tomcat using java code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256002/how-to-start-and-stop-tomcat-using-java-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you well, you are interested in running tomcat on your event from application. If it is the case, you can write your own method to run tomcat.

This is example:

```
public void stopRunTomcat(){
    try{
        Socket s = new Socket(server,8005);
        if(s.isConnected()){
            PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);
            //Stop tomcat if it is already started
            print.println("SHUTDOWN"); 
            print.close();
            s.close();
        }
        //Run tomcat 
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getProperty("catalina.home")+"\\bin\\startup.sh");
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You have to adopt this code to your paths and OS. After that you can call this method from event which have to raise tomcat.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you use maven give a look to it's cargo plugin: http://cargo.codehaus.org/Tomcat+7.x
I'm sure other build/dependency management tools have something similar as well.
(http://cargo.codehaus.org/Functional+testing)
Regards, Tamás