# Start an Apache server using a C# program

Tags: java, c#, apache

I would like to start an Apache Tomcat server on the localhost. Is it possible to write a Java or C# application that could start it whenever the user requires?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start Tomcat Server programmatically in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929175/how-to-start-tomcat-server-programmatically-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class in C# to execute a local process.

Comment: Thank you, it worked using Process.start("Process-url");