# Spring Boot Tomcat configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

```
Total time: 03:24 min  
 Finished at: 2017-01-16T21:31:55-06:00  
 Final Memory: 79M/508M
```

How can I set the maximum long running time of tomcat server in spring boot?

If its time is overdue then it throws Exception.

Comment: What means "embedded"? Are you starting tomcat programatically like http://blog.afkham.org/2011/09/embedding-tomcat-7-bettertomcat.html or like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929175?

Comment: What exception it throws???