# configuring web service from java program

Tags: java, web-services

I want to build a simple java web application from which I wish to change configuration of my web services like port number , protocol etc. Also start and stop them from the java program only.

Is it possible ?

As far I know I think changing the port requires changing the tomcat port and then restart it . So Is it possible to achieve using a java application.

Also how can I get my service work on soap and rest as per user's wish using java application.

Comment: This is not a java problem, you seriously need a better understanding about operating system structure first, before implementing things like this. Except if you do not care about your system's security.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with **Apache CXF**. It is simple to understand and with less configuration you can make your webservice up.

For controlling the tomcat like start and stop of the server, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256002/how-to-start-and-stop-tomcat-using-java-code)